# SQL Server Pagination using CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005

I have to apply paging on query as per requirement i need two extra columns other than query result

1. Total Records
2. Total Pages

but i am trying to confirm that this the right way to retrieve total number of pages

> ```
> CASE WHEN TotalRec%@PageSize > 0 THEN TotalRec/@PageSize) +1 ELSE TotalRec/@PageSize) END  TotalPage
> ```

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
        SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() TotalRec, ROW_Number() over(ORDER BY id) RowNo, ColumnOne, ColumnTwo
        FROM
        (           
        SELECT ColumnOne, ColumnTwo
        FROM table1 ct LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 IR ON ct.code=IR.code                         
        WHERE table1.code=3
        Group By  ColumnOne, ColumnTwo

        )ImmCat
)
    SELECT TotalRec TotalRec, 
    CASE WHEN TotalRec%@PageSize > 0 THEN TotalRec/@PageSize) +1 ELSE TotalRec/@PageSize) END  TotalPage 
    ,ColumnOne, ColumnTwo
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RowNoBETWEEN (((@PageNo - 1)*@PageSize) + 1) AND (@PageNo * @PageSize) order by RowNumber
```

Comment: [This article may be a useful read](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch). The `OFFSET/FETCH` syntax can't help you because of your versions, but I offer up a slightly more efficient way to write the CTE version.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes because of 2005 i can't use OFFSET/FETCH but I need your expert eye on my script, am i doing right to get total number of pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly avoid a conditional here, but you also do not need either `CEILING` or conversion to `numeric` to get the total number of pages if both `@totalrec` and `@pagesize` are integers (and it seems safe to assume that they are). The following formula will give you the number of pages to accommodate `@totalrec` rows given the page size of `@pagesize`:

```
(@totalrec - 1) / @pagesize + 1 AS TotalPages
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several typos, an ambiguous reference, possible div/0 and I can't tell if the input parameters are zero or one based so this is may need some tweaking.
I would make @TotalPage and @TotalRec OUTPUT parameters but for the sake of simplicity:

EDIT: Fixed a variable name, added parens, changed to assume zero based.

```
set @TotalRec = (select count(id) from table1 where code = 3)

if @TotalRec > 0 and @PageSize > 0
    set @TotalPage = @TotalRec/(@PageSize + 1)

set rowcount @PageSize

;with cte as (
    select
         row_number() over (order by id) as RowNo
        ,ColumnOne
        ,ColumnTwo
    from
        table1 ct
    left outer join table2 IR
        on ct.code=IR.code
    where ???.code = 3
)
select
     @TotalRec as TotalRec
    ,@TotalPage as TotalPage
    ,ColumnOne
    ,ColumnTwo
from cte
where RowNo > @PageNo * @PageSize
order by RowNo -- THIS IS IMPORTANT! DO NOT OMIT!
```

Comment: I believe statement SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() TotalRec" is better way to get total number of records instead of "set TotalRec = (select count(id) from table1 where code = 3) " Second "and TotalPage > 0"  is the statement to check number of total pages where as i am looking to write something to get this count ... third what if totalrec=30 and pagezise =10 your query will return 3+1 =4 total pages which is wrong

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() TotalRec is a major performance hit. Why do you think its better? You have aggregates that look like they are not needed and won't work as you coded there. over(ORDER BY id) won't work unless include ID in the group by.

Comment: because to get count before cte means i am gonna query same records(pages) two times? then why not COUNT(*) OVER() TotalRec ?

Comment: The count inside the cte is executing for every single record in the expression. Test it against a table with with few million records. Against 10 million records I get a few milliseconds vs 42 seconds.

Comment: That is to return just 10 records.

Answer (score 0):

There are two following ways to get Total number of pages, recommend is first.

**1.** `ceiling(convert(numeric(9,4),@totalrec)/convert(numeric(9,4),@pagesize)) as TotalPage`

**2.** `CASE WHEN TotalRec%@PageSize > 0 THEN TotalRec/@PageSize) +1 ELSE TotalRec/@PageSize) END  TotalPage`